# How to count the number of grouped attachments for a page in kentico 9?

Tags: kentico

I want to show a list of attachments, but only if there are any. If not, hide the containing div. How do I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are showing a list of attachments on the current document, you can get the number of grouped attachments with a macro:

```cs
{% CurrentDocument.GroupedAttachments["DocumentsAttached"].Count %}
```

`DocumentsAttached` would be the name of the field that contains the attachments.

On your attachments list webpart, you can set the value of the visibility field to the following macro:

```cs
{% CurrentDocument.GroupedAttachments["DocumentsAttached"].Count > 0 %}
```

Comment: How do I do this in ascx? I tried and got this:
[CMSAbstractTransformation.DataBind]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Are you listing out your pages in a repeater, and then in the transformation showing the attachments for each page?

Comment: The pages are in a transformation inside a universal viewer

Comment: And inside the transformation, are you using a `cms:DocumentAttachments` control to show the list of attachments?

Comment: Separately, yes. For what it's worth I ended up being able to get the count using a query and a custom macro. Thanks anyway though!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up accomplishing this with a custom query and function.